# Creating external UITableViewCell in Storyboard without .xib

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, uistoryboard

I have 2 different TableVC's with common cell. I can just copy the cell from one to another, but may be there is another way to archive it? I do not want to use .xib

Comment: Do you mean copy the content in the cell (image, label)? or the design (frame size, color) from other cell?

Comment: @Bejibun, cell design

Answer (score 0):

Here the thing you can do, if you want to have the same exact same of the cell. I just simply take a screenshot.

```
-(void)copyCell
{

    UITableViewCell * aCell = [_tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[_tblView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(aCell.frame.size);
    [aCell.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *aCellImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:aCellImage];

    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(aCell.frame.origin.x, aCell.frame.origin.y-offset, aCell.frame.size.width, aCell.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:imageView]; --->> change the self.view to your next tableView cell

}
```